# Position DIV relative to its neighbour

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want to position the div.product-video relative to its neighbour right bottom corner (when the screen is wider than 900px). Setting margin-top is not the solution I want because the height of the div.product-overview height is dynamic. Maybe there is a trick with negative margins? Hope someone can help me :-)

Edit:

I want the div.product-video stick to the bottom right corner of  div.product.overview when the screen is wider than 900px. Otherwise it should be displayed under the div.product-overview

Edit2:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWvA7.png)

I want to position div.product-video to the bottom right corner of div.product-overview independent of the height of div.product-overview.

[Link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fbr7arv0/)

HTML

```
<div class="product">
    <div class="product-overview">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <ul class="product-benefits">
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="product-video">
        <p>VIDEO</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.product
{
    width: 100%;
}

div.product-overview
{
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-width: 500px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: orangered;
    padding-right: 150px;
}

div.product-video
{
    float: left;
    min-width: 400px;
    width: 40%;
    max-width: 50%;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

@media (min-width: 900px)
{
    div.product-video
    {
        margin-left: -100px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Relative in what way? It's not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: could you show us with an image what should be the expected output?

Comment: I want the div.product-video stick to the bottom right corner of  div.product.overview when the screen is wider than 900px. Otherwise it should be displayed under the div.product-overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `@media` query should look like this:

`@media screen and (max-width: 900px)`

- Place the video div inside the overview. The overview is given `position: relative`
- The video div is given `position: absolute` and is positioned appropriately with right, left and bottom as needed

### Example

```css
div.product {
  width: 100%;
}
div.product-overview {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: 500px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: orangered;
  padding-right: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  position: relative;
}
div.product-video {
  min-width: 400px;
  width: 40%;
  max-width: 50%;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightblue;
  right: -200px;
  bottom: -50%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  div.product-video {
    left: 0;
    bottom: -250px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="product">
  <div class="product-overview">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <ul class="product-benefits">
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="product-video">
      <p>VIDEO</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, though it's not what I need. I added a picture to describe my problem better. [http://i.stack.imgur.com/aWvA7.png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aWvA7.png)